# angular filter object with empty values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following data:

```
 $scope.icons = [{
"id": 1,
"bonuses": [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Rob",  "amount": 10, "foreman": 1, "percA": 1, "percB": 0  },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Mark", "amount": 20, "foreman": 1, "percA": 1, "percB": 0  },
]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
"bonuses": [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Rob",  "amount": 11, "foreman": 1, "percA": 1, "percB": 0  },
  { "id": 2, "name": "", "amount": 30, "foreman": 1, "percA": 1, "percB": 0  },
]
  }, {
"id": 3,
"bonuses": [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Rob",  "amount": 10, "foreman": 1, "percA": 1, "percB": 0  },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Kent", "amount": 35, "foreman": 1, "percA": 1, "percB": 0  },
]
}];
```

this function inside the controller:

```
$scope.getBonusPeople = function() {

var bonusData = [];

angular.forEach($scope.icons, function(item) {

  angular.forEach(item.bonuses, function(bonusLine) {

    if (bonusData.indexOf(bonusLine) == -1 ) {
      bonusData.push(bonusLine);
    }

  })
});

return $scope.bonusPeople = bonusData;
}
```

and this is the result:

```
Rob - 10
Mark - 20
Rob - 11
- 30
Rob - 10
Kent - 35
```

I am trying to find only the lines that the bonuses.name has a value.

the result should be

```
Rob - 10
Mark - 20
Rob - 11
Rob - 10
Kent - 35
```

how can i do that.

here is a plunkler http://plnkr.co/edit/wZpr0nerqti4L2Yg37iT?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a check to see if name is not an empty string. See the snippet below.

```
angular.forEach($scope.icons, function (item) {
    angular.forEach(item.bonuses, function (bonusLine) {
        if (bonusData.indexOf(bonusLine) == -1 && bonusLine.name !== '') {
            bonusData.push(bonusLine);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: it worked.  thank you all.  i tried something similar but obviously not exactly as yours.  thanx again.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if name has a value. If it does, proceed with your current logic:

```
angular.forEach($scope.icons, function(item) {
  angular.forEach(item.bonuses, function(bonusLine) {
    if(bonusLine.name!=='') {
        if (bonusData.indexOf(bonusLine) == -1 ) {
          bonusData.push(bonusLine);
        }
    }
  })
});
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/E9bXzn8Jt2B8yJ3IU33s?p=preview